# Query Was Empty por que?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el Siguiente Codigo y me aparece en pantalla al principio de la tabla :
Query Was Empty

```
$userId=$_SESSION['u_id'];

$resultMyVouchers="SELECT oc.order_id, oc.order_amount, oc.coupon_id, oc.products_id, oc.purchased_by, oc.order_transaction_id, oc.options_id, oc.order_price, p.city_id, p.product_name, p.deal_status, p.product_closing_date, p.side_deal FROM orders oc LEFT JOIN products p ON oc.products_id=p.product_id WHERE oc.uid='".$userId."' AND oc.order_types='me' AND oc.order_transaction_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY oc.order_id DESC";

$rsMyVouchers=dbQuery($resultMyVouchers); 

    echo '<div>';
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
    echo '<thead>';  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<th><strong>Cupon</strong></th>";  
    echo "<th><strong>Fecha de Compra</strong></th>";  
    echo "<th><strong>Monto</strong></th>";
    echo "<th><strong>Estatus</strong></th>";
    echo "<th><strong>Respuesta</strong></th>";  
    echo "</tr>";
    echo '</thead>';  



    if(mysql_num_rows($rsMyVouchers)){
        while($row=dbFetchArray($rsMyVouchers)){

            $srtCoupon="SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE coupon_id='".$row['coupon_id']."' AND coupon_status='available' AND coupon_used='no'";
            $responseCoupon=dbQuery($strCoupon);
            $rsCoupon=dbFetchArray($responseCoupon);    

                echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".date("Y / M / d H:i", dateTimeStamp($rsCoupon['coupon_purchase_date']))."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$row['order_price']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['deal_status']."</td>";
                echo "<td>"."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";




                    }

            }else{
                echo "no Recibo datos";
                } 
            echo "</table>";
            echo '</div>';
```

Haciendo Pruebas Descubrí que la linea que hace error es una consulta dentro del While:

```
$srtCoupon="SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE coupon_id='".$row['coupon_id']."' AND coupon_status='available' AND coupon_used='no'";
$responseCoupon=dbQuery($strCoupon);
$rsCoupon=dbFetchArray($responseCoupon);
```

Cuando elimino esta consulta los datos se muestran pero evidentemente no los datos que necesito de la consulta Adicional.
La idea General es que Muestre la fecha de compra del cupon que esta almacenada en otra tabla y por eso trato de ejecutar la consulta dentro del while para obtener la fecha de cada resultado encontrado.

Comment: `Query Was Empty` significa que esa consulta no arrojó ningún dato. Deberás entonces controlar esa posibilidad en el código y mostrar un mensaje o contenido apropiado en caso de que esa consulta no encuentre datos. Esa solución debe ser parte de la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: Por lo general abrir de ese modo *consultas dentro de consultas,* y dentro de un bucle, podría ser una mala práctica. Si tus tablas están relacionadas, puedes obtener mediante `JOIN` todos los datos necesarios **mediante una sola consulta** y luego presentar los resultados. Si en tu bucle `while` hay 100, 94566, o 1 millón de datos, tú estarás ejecutando esa misma cantidad de llamadas a la base de datos, lo cual podría ser dramático y tumbar tu aplicación en algunos casos.